# Lower Bound on the sum $S = \sum_{m = k}^{N} {m \choose k} \cdot a^{N - m}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, contest-math, binomial-coefficients, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I would like to determine a lower bound on the expression
$$S = \sum_{m = k}^{N} {m \choose k} \cdot a^{N - m}$$
where $a > 1$.

Since this sum does not have a nice expression, as shown by:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bm+%3D+k%7D%5E%7BT%7D+%7Bm+%5Cchoose+k%7D+*+a%5E%7BT+-+m%7D
, I would need to determine a nice, yet not too weak, lower bound on the sum $S$.

An approach I had was the following:

I denoted $a_m = {m \choose k}$ and $b_m = a^{N - m}$, hence:
$$S = \sum_{m = k}^N a_m \cdot b_m$$
where the 2 sums are equal to
$$\sum_{m = k}^N a_m = {N + 1 \choose k + 1} $$
$$\sum_{m = k}^N b_m = \frac{a^{N - k + 1} - 1}{a - 1}$$
And then my idea was to use Chebyshev Sum Inequality. However the problem is that the 2 sequences $a_m$ and $b_m$ are one increasing and one decreasing, hence this would lead to an upper bound instead:
$$ S \leq \frac{1}{N - k + 1} (\sum_{m} a_m)(\sum_{m} b_m)$$, but what I would need is a lower bound.

If you have any idea I would be extremely grateful.

**Later Edit**: Using the idea of @MarkS. to rewrite the sum, there might be following way to obtain a lower bound:

We start directly from:
$$S' = \sum_{i = 0}^{N - k} {k + i \choose k} \cdot b^i$$
where $b = 1/a$ and $S = a^{N - k} \cdot S'$.

Now for the binomial coefficient we can use the inequality: ${n \choose k} \geq (\frac{n}{k})^k$, which in our case will give us:
$$S' \geq \sum_{i = 0}^{N - k} b^i \cdot \left(1 + \frac{i}{k} \right)^k$$
Then for $\left(1 + \frac{i}{k} \right)^k$ we will use Bernoulli inequality which will then give us:
$$S' \geq \sum_{i = 0}^{N - k} b^i \cdot (1 + i) $$
where the rhs can be computed exactly and will give us:
$$S' \geq \frac{b (b^{N-k} - 1)}{b - 1} + \frac{b ((N-k) b^{N -k + 1} - (N - k + 1) b^{N -k} + 1)}{(b - 1)^2}$$

By replacing $b = 1/a$ we get:
$$S' \geq \frac{2a^{N - k + 1} - a^{N - k} - 2a - (N - k)(a - 1) + 1}{(a - 1)a^{N - k}}$$
Hence we would obtain:
$$S \geq \frac{2a^{N - k + 1} - a^{N - k} - 2a - (N - k)(a - 1) + 1}{(a - 1)}$$

Maybe the Bernoulli inequality is not the strongest I could use at that point, but I am not sure what else I could do.

Comment: I don't know if this leads anywhere, but my first thought was to rewrite as $a^{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k}{k+n \choose n}b^{n}$ where $b=1/a$, since a sum from $0$  might be more recognizable and it might help to match up the exponent to the index.

Comment: @MarkS. This is a nicer form, I agree. But it should be $k + n \choose k$, right?

Comment: @MarkS. I started from your idea to rewrite the sum, to obtain a lower bound, which I added in the main text. Let me know what you think. :)

Comment: I chose to write $k+n \choose n$ intentionally, but they're equal so whichever seems easier to use.

Comment: You are right, sorry, my bad